# SwiftUI - Memory Leaks

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory-leaks, swiftui

#### Environment

- Catalina 10.15.7
- Xcode 12.0
- Swift 5.0

---

#### Brief explanation

- Problem
  Having memory leaks in the `AppDelegate`.
- Goal
  Fix them and avoid not to be occured again.
- Question
  What could be the reasons that cause the problems and where should I take a look or investigate time?

---

I have been working on an app with SwiftUI for a couple of months and have created most of the features that I wanted for the beta version.
Now I have memory leaks that I can see from the instrument tools, and a screenshot is below.
[image]

It points to the first line of the class `AppDelegate` and doesn't tell us what causes the problem.
The number of detection of the leaks grows as we use the app.

I am happy to provide more information if you need.
Thank you.

---

#### Code

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit
import FacebookCore
import FBSDKCoreKit
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application( application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions )
        return true
    }
    
    func application( _ app:UIApplication, open url:URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey :Any] = [:] ) -> Bool { ApplicationDelegate.shared.application( app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation] )
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you show code of `ApplicationDelegate`?

Comment: @Asperi Thank you for your comment. I've attached the code of `AppDelegate.swift` to the original post.

Comment: Can you try to debug the memory leaks using the Xcode memory graph debugger? You can find more information doing so.

Comment: @Robert Thank you for your comment. I’ve also tried with that, and it pointed to the same first line of AppDelegate class. I couldn’t find any methods that I implemented by myself from the debugger.

Comment: I was seeing something similar to this, but now I'm on Big Sur 11.0.1 the leaks have gone.

Comment: I tried to see if there are leaks on the Landmark app that I created by following the official SwiftUI tutorial provided by Apple, and it turned out that there are. So I conclude that the leaks probably come from SwiftUI itself.